# How are you supposed to find n of an n-sided polygon given part of two interior angles

Tags: polygons, angle

I need to work out the below question, but I have no idea what to do.
I tried researching but the results were assuming that I know the entire interior angle
And I'm not even sure if this is a polygon, since it isn't closed.

Link to diagram, because I don't have enough reputation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAC9a.jpg

Anyway if anyone knows how to work this out, it'll be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$BCDEF$ is an irregular pentagon so it angles add up to $540$. The angles at $B$ and $F$ are $45$ and lets call the angles at $C,D$ and $E$, $\theta$ then we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
3 \theta+2 \times 45 =540.
\end{eqnarray*}
Can you work the rest out ?